# matrix equation with vector variable and covariance matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, covariance, transpose

How to solve the following matrix equation involving transpose conjugates: $x*x^H=S$, where $x$ is the variable: a column complex vector, and $S$ is a covariance matrix (Hermitian positive semi-definite)? Is there any closed-form solution? The operator .$H$ indicated the Hermitian operation (transpose conjugate).

Comment: The left hand side has rank one, so in general this cannot be solved exactly.

Comment: Your question is how to solve for $x$ given $xx^H = S$ ?

Comment: Thanks @WimC for such observation.

Comment: Yes, @AhmadBazzi, that was the question, but it is in general not soluble as already pointed out.